# Get address from Postal Code and Country (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={zipcode})

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to get the street information of a location from its Postal Code and country, as seen in the picture I get only the location of the place from the Postal Code and Country but no further information of the place. I want to do it somewhat like the auto complete form in the link. Where users get back all their address information after entering their Postal Code .

If there are addresses with the same the Postal Code is there a way to display them like a list which the users can chose from.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Can I use this code to get the data I want?

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={zipcode}`

[image]

Comment: Google is asking for more than a zip code.  They have a list of all the streets.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: As soon as you type the beginning of a street name into their form, Google looks up the street name and gets the zip code and other address information.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc is it possible to reverse engineer it so that when the user types in their country and zipcode, Google looks up it up and display the address and street name?

Comment: There is more than one street in a zip code.  There is one and only one zip code when you have a street number and street name.  So, no.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc what about general location is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer, but I can't post images in the comments and it's obvious that the OP doesn't understand address lookup.

This image is from the [Google Maps Platform Samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) page.

[image: Google Form]

If all you have is a zip code, the only reliable information you can get is the state.  I chose the city from a drop-down list that I couldn't screen capture.

The purpose of this sample form is to capture an exact address.  Now, if you were actually using this form on a website, there would need to be a second line address for apartment numbers, suite numbers, or other identifiers of an address.

Now, when I type in an actual street address, I get this information.

[image: Google Form 2]

I had to type all the way through Avenue before Google could give me an exact match.

It's obvious that Google has a database with all the zip codes in the United States and perhaps elsewhere where they can verify that an address is real.  For some businesses, this verification is worth the price.

To specifically answer the OP's question, the answer is no.  No.  All you can get from a zip code is the state.